# List command not displaying all output

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Trying to connect to multiple machines using bash on a machine that has the public ssh keys for the others and run a command on them to display the output on this machine. If I use the '**$a**' variable as in the code below when I execute the script I get this uncompleted output

```
    bash: total: command not found
    bash: line 1: drwxr-xr-x: command not found
    bash: line 2: drwxr-xr-x: command not found
    bash: line 3: -rw-r--r--: command not found
    bash: line 5: -rwxr-xr-x: command not found
    ....
```

However if I use the commented block without calling the **$a** variable the bash prints the correct output of the command.

The code executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ls -lah)
for i in "machine1" "machine2" 

do ssh root\@"$i" "$a; exit;"
*#do ssh root\@"$i" "ls -lah; exit;" - displays accordingly*
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because `a=$(ls -lah)` assigns `ls -lah`'s output to variable `a`. Change it to `a='ls -lah'` and it will be ok.

See command substitution section in your bash's manual

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have another answer which i have been using for a long time.

```sh
declare machines=("user@machine1" "user@machine2")
command="ls -lah"
for machine in "${machines[@]}"
do
  ssh "$machine" "$command"
done
```

**$a** did not work because it will be executed.

Comment: How can I store the result of command in an array for later use? For example I want to take a number of running processes of their machines and want to display it somehow

Comment: If you want to store the result in an array:
you can do something like this `declare -a result_array=()` this is to declare an array. now append data to it like this `result_array+=("data")`.
you can echo the final result `${result_array[@]}` or loop through this variable and do the required operations.

Comment: Tried that, I put result_array+=("$command) inside the loop but  I want the have the output of $command not printing it, I get only a bunch of "ls -lah" printing.